# ¿Cómo crear tarjetas de mi página para facebook y twitter?

Tags: html, html5, seo, redes-sociales

Leí que para crear una tarjeta al compartir mi página en una red social, tengo que utilizar las etiquetas `meta`. Y segun leí, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="description" content="Informacion del Corona virus en el mundo, el virus que inicio en Wuhan, en la provincia de Hubei, en China y tiene al mundo entero preocupado" />
<meta name="keywords" content="sedes, potosi, sedes potosi, coronavirus, COVID-19, salud 2019, muertes por coronavirus, recuperados corona virus" />


<meta property="og:title" content="SEDES POTOSI, SARS-CoV-2, Covid-19">
<meta property="og:description" content="Informacion del Corona virus en el mundo, el virus que inicio en Wuhan, en la provincia de Hubei, en China y tiene al mundo entero preocupado">

<meta property="og:url" content="{{route('covid.pais')}}">
<meta property="og:image" content="{{asset('dist/map.jpg')}}">

<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Shassain666" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@Shassain666" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{{asset('dist/map.jpg')}}" />
```

Al publicarlo en facebook, el card me sale de forma exitosa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Problema es con `Twitter`, el cual no me reconoce la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué sucede esto?

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la Documentación, https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started

> El ejemplo siguiente utiliza una combinación de etiquetas de Twitter y
>   Open Graph para definir una tarjeta de resumen:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimesbits" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@nickbilton" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/12/08/a-twitter-for-my-sister/" />
<meta property="og:title" content="A Twitter for My Sister" />
<meta property="og:description" content="In the early days, Twitter grew so quickly that it was almost impossible to add new features because engineers spent their time trying to keep the rocket ship from stalling." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2011/12/08/technology/bits-newtwitter/bits-newtwitter-tmagArticle.jpg" />
```